# Is there way to provide a date converter for Elasticsearch Java API?

Tags: java, date, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-jest

I have a legacy domain object that stores date/times in milliseconds as a long. I now want to index this object in ES using JestClient, which is just a wrapper around the ES Java API.

Is there a way to tell ES to convert this long value to a Date in say the `strict_date_time_no_millis` format (`"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZ"`) while indexing? If so, is it then possible to tell ES to convert the Date back to milliseconds when retrieving the results?

Answer (score 0):

There is a difference in what elasticsearch stores in the index and how it returns the original value. The original value is what elasticsearch returns when a document is matched. Using the mapping you can define how a field is handled. When you specify that a field is a date, you can pass a string with a certain format, but you can also provide a long with the time in milliseconds. I do not see elasticsearch convert the actual passed value in the document returned when it is matched.

Does that help?